# Добавление в форму наследника от базового компонента

Tags: java, javafx

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь добавить в pane leftPane объект MarkEditPanel, но MarkEditPanel не добавляется. В чем ошибка?

```
public class MainSceneFXMLController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Pane leftPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
                    leftPane.getChildren().add(new MarkEditPanel());
    }
}

public class MarkEditPanel extends Pane{
    private MarkEditPanelController markEditPanelController;
    public MarkEditPanel() {
        markEditPanelController = new MarkEditPanelController();
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
                getClass().getResource("/fxml/MarkEditPanel.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(this.markModelRelation);
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}

public class MarkEditPanelController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private VBox vBoxPane;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            TextField textFieldmarkName = new TextField();
            vBoxPane.getChildren().add(textFieldmarkName );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в `/fxml/MarkEditPanel.fxml` корневой элемент выглядит так

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">

</fx:root>
```

то необходимо кроме `fxmlLoader.setController(this.markModelRelation);`  также отсетерить `fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);`

Если же корневой элемент

```
<VBox> ... </VBox>
```

то нужно добавить его в MarkEditPanel  так `getChildren().add(fxmlLoader.load());` или после load() можно взять `fxmlLoader.getRoot()`

Comment: Да, второй вариант отлично подошел в моей ситуации. Большое спасибо.